# Python 3.3.2 - trying to read url from wunderground

Tags: python, json

I have been struggling for a while trying to convert some code from an older version of Python.  I'm simply trying to run an api lookup from wunderground and I can't get past my errors in python.  Here is the error: 
f = urllib.request.urlopen(fileName)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

The code is pretty straight forward, I know i"m missing something simple, thanks for any help.

```
import urllib
import json

key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
zip = input('For which ZIP code would you like to see the weather? ')
fileName = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + key +    "/geolookup/conditions/q/PA/" + zip + ".json"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(fileName)
json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print ("Current temperature in %s is: %s % (location, temp_f)")
close()
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes importing a package (e.g. `numpy`) automatically imports submodules (e.g. `numpy.linalg`) into its namespace. But that is not the case for `urllib`. So you need to use

```
import urllib.request
```

instead of

```
import urllib
```

in order to access the `urllib.request` module. Alternatively, you could use

```
import urllib.request as request
```

in order to access the module as `request`.

Looking at the [examples in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples) is a good way to avoid problems like this in the future.

---

Since `f.read()` returns a `bytes` object, and `json.loads` expects a `str`, you'll also need to decode the bytes. The particular encoding depends on what the server decides to send you; in this case the bytes are `utf-8` encoded. So use

```
json_string = f.read().decode('utf-8')
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
```

to decode the bytes.

---

There is a small typo on the last line. Use

```
print ("Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f))
```

to interpolate the string `"Current temperature in %s is: %s"` with the values `(location, temp_f)`. Note the placement of the quotation mark.

---

Tip: Since `zip` is a builtin-function, it is a good practice not to name a
variable `zip` since this changes the usual meaning of `zip` making it harder
for others and perhaps future-you to understand your code. The fix is easy: change `zip` to something else like `zip_code`.

---

```
import urllib.request as request
import json

key = ...
zip_code = input('For which ZIP code would you like to see the weather? ')
fileName = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + key +    "/geolookup/conditions/q/PA/" + zip_code + ".json"
f = request.urlopen(fileName)
json_string = f.read().decode('utf-8')
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
print ("Current temperature in %s is: %s" % (location, temp_f))
```

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me find my mistakes when I am using IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [requests library Python HTTP for Humans.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), the code below will work on either python2 or 3:

```
import requests
key = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
# don't shadow builtin zip function
zip_code = input('For which ZIP code would you like to see the weather? ')
fileName = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/{}/geolookup/conditions/q/PA/{}.json".format(key, zip_code)
parsed_json = requests.get(fileName).json()
location = parsed_json['location']['city']
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
# pass actual variables and use str.format
print ("Current temperature in {} is: {}%f".format(location, temp_f))
```

Getting the json is simply `requests.get(fileName).json()`, using `str.format` is the preferred method and I find less prone to errors, it is also far more feature-rich in comparison to the older `printf` style formatting.

You can see it works under both 2 and 3 with a sample run:

```
:~$ python3 weat.py
For which ZIP code would you like to see the weather? 12212
Current temperature in Albany is: 68.9%f
:~$ python2 weat.py
For which ZIP code would you like to see the weather? 12212
Current temperature in Albany is: 68.9%f
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just changing to the requests.get().json() worked great.

Comment: No prob, requests does a lot of the hard work for you.